# MySQL stored function gives error (if - else)

Tags: mysql, if-statement, stored-functions

I have a stored function which won't execute well, but I don't know what I am doing wrong. I want to check if the key exists in the database.

- if so -> then update
- else -> create

```sql
BEGIN

IF EXISTS(SELECT MenuItemID FROM menuitem WHERE MenuItemID=_MenuItemID)
    BEGIN
    UPDATE menuitem SET MenuID=_MenuID,ParentMenuID=_ParentMenuID,PosIndex=_PosIndex,XamlFileID=_XamlFileID,CanExpand=_CanExpand WHERE MenuItemID=_MenuItemID;
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO menuitem (MenuItemID,MenuID,ParentMenuID,PosIndex,XamlFileID,CanExpand) VALUES (_MenuIt5nuID,_ParentMenuID,_PosIndex,_XamlFileID,_CanExpand);
    END

RETURN ('success');

END
```

Comment: Are you setting delimiters? AND every if needs a THEN and and END IF

Comment: AND mysql does not require begin..end blocks in if statements. Apart from all that using a function for an upsert seems a bit odd.

Comment: Why don't you use **INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**??? Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: @nacho ON DUPLICAT KEY is not available in functions

Comment: Why do you feel you have to use a function at all?

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the syntax errors - you will need to adjust the input parameters.

```
drop function if exists f;
delimiter $$
create function f(inf varchar(10))
returns varchar(10)
BEGIN

IF EXISTS(SELECT MenuItemID FROM menuitem WHERE MenuItemID=_MenuItemID) then
    UPDATE menuitem 
        SET MenuID=_MenuID,ParentMenuID=_ParentMenuID,PosIndex=_PosIndex,XamlFileID=_XamlFileID,CanExpand=_CanExpand 
         WHERE MenuItemID=_MenuItemID;
ELSE
    INSERT INTO menuitem (MenuItemID,MenuID,ParentMenuID,PosIndex,XamlFileID,CanExpand) VALUES 
     (_MenuIt5nuID,_ParentMenuID,_PosIndex,_XamlFileID,_CanExpand);
end if;

RETURN ('success');

END $$

delimiter ;
```